# Meaning of ___はんは

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, manga, contractions, sports

In a manga about boxing, the protagonist is going to fight an american boxer. His trainer is telling him how he should train:

白人はんは"拳"を鍛えてるだろうがお前は"足"だ。

I don't understand what "…はんは" is. Is it a contraction of "はのは"? If so, what is its meaning? [Here is the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lidt.jpg) where it is taken from. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the name of the manga? Is it リクドウ 7? Does the trainer routinely refer to people as 「はん」instead of 「さん」?

Comment: Yes it's リクドウ 7. The trainer doesn't usually refer to people neither with 「はん」nor with 「さん」. He is quite a rude character. Is 「はん」a colloquial version of 「さん」?

Comment: It is dialectical. Mainly around western Japan (Osaka, Kyoto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はん is an uncommon dialectal name suffix similar to さん. It's widely known as a Kyoto-ben word. I may be stereotyped, but はん is typically used by *maiko/geisha*.

The person who said this is not a Kyoto-ben speaker, right? Then I think he used it as a mild joke. はん has a old-fashioned/pre-modern overtone (Kyoto was an ancient capital of Japan), so using はん can imply the American opponent is more advanced.